# Find the counter of a specific value in a two-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

I want to find out if a two-dimensional array contains a specific value.
Take this random matrix for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int m;
    int n;
    int mat[100][100];

    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    printf("\nEnter the number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = rand() % 21;
            printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

How to find out how many zeros (0s) are in a `mat[i][j]` array?

Comment: Think about this: you managed to fill the values of the matrix, the question is how did you do it? So, can you use that information for your next question? How can I go through all values of the matrix and check if a certain value is present? If you did actually write the code shown in the question, the next part should be a piece a cake.

Comment: Well, the obvious way is `for(i = 0; i < m; i++) for(j = 0; j < n; j++) if(mat[j][j] == 0) count++;`.  Is there a reason you can't just use that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends, are you allowed to save this info when you actually fill in the matrix?

```
int numZeroes = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        mat[i][j] = rand() % 21;

        if (mat[i][j] == 0) {
            numZeroes++;
        }

        printf("%d\t", mat[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
```

If you can't and you just need to determine how many zeroes are in the matrix after it has been initialized, you need to brute force search it since it is not sorted at all, using the same type of nested loops you used to initialize it:

```
int numZeroes = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (mat[i][j] == 0) {
            numZeroes++;
        }
    }
```